# How to generate random, typed functions

Tags: haskell, typechecking

I would like to programmatically generate random Haskell functions and evaluate them. It seems to me that the only way to do this is to basically generate Haskell code programatically and run it using the GHC API or an external process, returning a string, and parsing it back into a Haskell data type. Is this true?

My reasoning is that as follows. The functions are polymorphic so I can't use Typeable. More importantly, even if I write my own type checker and annotate each function with its type, I can't prove to the Haskell compiler that my type checker is correct. For example, when I pull two functions out of a heterogenous collection of functions and apply one to the other, I need to provide the compiler with a guarantee that the function I'm using to choose these functions only chooses functions with corresponding types. But there is no way to do this, right?

Comment: When fully evaluated, will the functions all have the same result type?

Comment: @mhwombat Yes, they will.

Comment: What result and argument types should the functions have? It may be worth looking at for instance the Arbitrary and CoArbitrary classes in QuickCheck, which are used to randomly generate functions for testing purposes.

Also, if you really need to bypass the typechecker, you can do it using unsafeCoerce. This is actually used internally in Typeable's cast function.

Comment: What about `foo :: a -> b; foo _ = unsafeCoerce (unsafePerformIO randomIO :: Integer)` ;-)

Comment: how about you create a type-level RNG built on type-level nats. You'd have to change the seed by hand I suppose, to get different results between runs

Comment: What about the `Fun` helpers in `Text.QuickCheck.Arbitrary`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

DarkOtter's comment mentions QuickCheck's `Arbitrary` and `CoArbitrary` classes, which are certainly the first thing you should try.  QuickCheck has this instance:

```
instance (CoArbitrary a, Arbitrary b) => Arbitrary (a -> b) where ...
```

As it happens, I was just yesterday reading the QuickCheck code to understand how this works, so I can just share what I learned while it's fresh in my mind.  QuickCheck is built around a type that looks like this (and this won't be exactly the same):

```
type Size = Int

-- | A generator for random values of type @a@.
newtype Gen a = 
    MkGen { -- | Generate a random @a@ using the given randomness source and
            -- size. 
            unGen :: StdGen -> Size -> a 
          }

class Arbitrary a where
    arbitrary :: a -> Gen a
```

The first trick is that QuickCheck has a function that works like this (and I didn't work out exactly how it's implemented):

```
-- | Use the given 'Int' to \"perturb\" the generator, i.e., to make a new
-- generator that produces different pseudorandom results than the original.
variant :: Int -> Gen a -> Gen a
```

Then they use this to implement various instances of this `CoArbitrary` class:

```
class CoArbitrary a where
    -- | Use the given `a` to perturb some generator.
    coarbitrary :: a -> Gen b -> Gen b

-- Example instance: we just treat each 'Bool' value as an 'Int' to perturb with.
instance CoArbitrary Bool where
    coarbitrary False = variant 0
    coarbitrary True = variant 1
```

Now with these pieces in place, we want this:

```
instance (Coarbitrary a, Arbitrary b) => Arbitrary (a -> b) where
    arbitrary = ...
```

I won't write out the implementation, but the idea is this:

1. Using the `CoArbitrary` instance of `a` and the `Arbitrary` instance of `b` we can make the function `\a -> coarbitrary a arbitrary`, which has type `a -> Gen b`.
2. Remember that `Gen b` is a newtype for `StdGen -> Size -> b`, so the type `a -> Gen b` is isomorphic to `a -> StdGen -> Size -> b`.
3. We can trivially write a function that takes any function of that latter type and switches the argument order around to return a function of type `StdGen -> Size -> a -> b`.
4. This rearranged type is isomorphic to `Gen (a -> b)`, so voilà, we pack the rearranged function into a `Gen`, and we got our random function generator!

I would recommend that you read the source of QuickCheck to see this for yourself.  When you tackle that, you're only going to run into two extra details that might slow you down.  First, the Haskell `RandomGen` class has this method:

```
-- | The split operation allows one to obtain two distinct random generators.
split :: RandomGen g => g -> (g, g)
```

This operation is used in the `Monad` instance for `Gen`, and is rather important.  One of the tricks here is that the `StdGen` is a pure pseudo random number generator; the way `Gen (a -> b)` works is that for each possible value of `a` we perturb a `b` generator, use that perturbed generator to generate the `b` result, but then we **never advance the perturbed generator's state**; basically the generated `a -> b` function is a closure over a pseudo-random seed, and each time we call it with some `a` we use that specific `a` to deterministically create a new seed, and then use that to deterministically generate a `b` that depends on `a` and the hidden seed.

The abbreviated type `Seed -> a -> b` more or less sums up what's going on—a pseudo-random function is a rule for generating a `b` from a pseudo-random seed and an `a`.  This won't work with imperative-style stateful random number generators.

Second: instead of directly having a `(a -> StdGen -> Size -> b) -> StdGen -> Size -> a -> b` function as I describe above, the QuickCheck code has `promote :: Monad m => m (Gen a) -> Gen (m a)`, which is the generalization of that to any `Monad`.  When `m` is the function instance of `Monad`, `promote` coincides with `(a -> Gen b) -> Gen (a -> b)`, so it's really the same as I sketch above.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the very thorough answers above! None of the responses, quite did what I was looking for though. I followed up on DarkOtter's suggestion in the comment the question, and used `unsafeCoerce` avoid the type checker. The basic idea is that we create a GADT that packages up Haskell functions with their types; the type system I use follows pretty closely Mark P. Jones' ["Typing Haskell in Haskell."](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/thih/) Whenever I want a collection of Haskell functions, I first coerce them into `Any` types, then I do what I need to do, stitching them together randomly. When I go to evaluate the new functions, first I coerce them back to the type I wanted. Of course, this isn't safe; if my type checker is wrong or I annotate the haskell functions with incorrect types, then I end up with nonsense.

I've pasted the code I tested this with below. Note that there are two local modules being imported `Strappy.Type` and `Strappy.Utils`. The first is the type system mentioned above. The second brings in helpers for the stochastic programs.

Note: in the code below I'm using the combinatory logic as the basic language. That's why my expression language only has application and no variables or lambda abstraction.

```
{-# Language GADTs,  ScopedTypeVariables   #-}

import Prelude hiding (flip)
import qualified  Data.List as List
import Unsafe.Coerce (unsafeCoerce) 
import GHC.Prim
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Identity
import Control.Monad.Random

import Strappy.Type
import Strappy.Utils (flip)


-- | Helper for turning a Haskell type to Any. 
mkAny :: a -> Any
mkAny x = unsafeCoerce x 


-- | Main data type. Holds primitive functions (Term), their
-- application (App) and annotations.
data Expr a where
    Term :: {eName  :: String, 
             eType  :: Type, 
             eThing :: a} -> Expr a
    App  :: {eLeft  :: (Expr (b -> a)),
             eRight :: (Expr b),
             eType  :: Type}         ->  Expr a 

-- | smart constructor for applications
a <> b = App a b (fst . runIdentity . runTI $ typeOfApp a b)

instance Show (Expr a)   where
    show Term{eName=s} = s
    show App{eLeft=el, eRight=er} = "(" ++ show el ++ " " ++  show er ++ ")"



-- | Return the resulting type of an application. Run's type
-- unification.
typeOfApp :: Monad m => Expr a -> Expr b -> TypeInference  m Type
typeOfApp e_left e_right 
    = do t <- newTVar Star 
         case mgu (eType e_left) (eType e_right ->- t) of 
           (Just sub) -> return $ toType (apply sub (eType e_left))
           Nothing -> error $ "typeOfApp: cannot unify " ++
                      show e_left ++ ":: " ++ show (eType e_left) 
                               ++ " with " ++ 
                      show e_right ++ ":: " ++ show (eType e_right ->- t) 

eval :: Expr a -> a
eval Term{eThing=f} = f
eval App{eLeft=el, eRight=er} = (eval el) (eval er)

filterExprsByType :: [Any] -> Type -> TypeInference [] Any
filterExprsByType (e:es) t  
    = do et <- freshInst (eType (unsafeCoerce e :: Expr a))
         let e' = unsafeCoerce e :: Expr a
         case mgu et t of
           Just sub -> do let eOut = unsafeCoerce e'{eType = apply sub et} :: Any
                          return eOut `mplus` rest
           Nothing -> rest
      where rest = filterExprsByType es t
filterExprsByType [] t = lift []


----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Library of functions

data Library = Library { probOfApp :: Double, -- ^ probability of an expansion
                         libFunctions :: [Any] }

cInt2Expr :: Int -> Expr Int
-- | Convert numbers to expressions. 
cInt2Expr i = Term (show i) tInt i 


--  Some basic library entires. 
t = mkTVar 0                  
t1 = mkTVar 1                  
t2 = mkTVar 2                  
t3 = mkTVar 3                  

cI = Term "I" (t ->- t) id
cS = Term "S" (((t2 ->- t1 ->- t) ->- (t2 ->- t1) ->- t2 ->- t)) $ \f g x -> (f x) (g x)
cB = Term "B" ((t1 ->- t) ->- (t2 ->- t1) ->- t2 ->- t) $ \f g x -> f (g x)
cC = Term "C" ((t2 ->- t1 ->- t2 ->- t) ->- t1 ->- t2 ->- t) $ \f g x -> (f x) g x
cTimes :: Expr (Int -> Int -> Int)
cTimes = Term "*" (tInt ->- tInt ->- tInt) (*)
cPlus :: Expr (Int -> Int -> Int)
cPlus = Term "+" (tInt ->- tInt ->- tInt) (+)
cCons = Term ":"  (t ->- TAp tList t ->- TAp tList t)  (:)
cAppend = Term "++" (TAp tList t ->- TAp tList t ->- TAp tList t) (++)
cHead = Term "head" (TAp tList t ->- t) head
cMap = Term "map" ((t ->- t1) ->- TAp tList t ->- TAp tList t1) map
cEmpty = Term "[]" (TAp tList t) []
cSingle = Term "single" (t ->- TAp tList t) $ \x -> [x]
cRep = Term "rep" (tInt ->- t ->- TAp tList t) $ \n x -> take n (repeat x)
cFoldl = Term "foldl" ((t ->- t1 ->- t) ->- t ->- (TAp tList t1) ->- t) $ List.foldl'
cNums =  [cInt2Expr i | i <- [1..10]]

--  A basic library

exprs :: [Any]
exprs = [mkAny cI, 
         mkAny cS, 
         mkAny cB, 
         mkAny cC, 
         mkAny cTimes, 
         mkAny cCons, 
         mkAny cEmpty,
         mkAny cAppend,
--         mkAny cHead,
         mkAny cMap,
         mkAny cFoldl,
         mkAny cSingle,
         mkAny cRep
        ] 
        ++ map mkAny cNums

library = Library 0.3 exprs


-- | Initializing a TypeInference monad with a Library. We need to
-- grab all type variables in the library and make sure that the type
-- variable counter in the state of the TypeInference monad is greater
-- that that counter.
initializeTI :: Monad m => Library -> TypeInference m ()
initializeTI Library{libFunctions=es} = do put (i + 1)
                                           return ()
    where go n (expr:rest) = let tvs = getTVars (unsafeCoerce expr :: Expr a)
                                 getTVars expr = tv . eType $ expr
                                 m = maximum $ map (readId . tyVarId) tvs 
                             in if null tvs then 0 else go (max n m) rest
          go n [] = n
          i = go 0 es


----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Main functions. 
sampleFromExprs :: (MonadPlus m, MonadRandom m) =>
                   Library -> Type -> TypeInference  m (Expr a)
-- | Samples a combinator of type t from a stochastic grammar G. 
sampleFromExprs lib@Library{probOfApp=prApp, libFunctions=exprs} tp 
    = do initializeTI lib
         tp' <- freshInst tp
         sample tp'
    where sample tp = do
            shouldExpand <- flip prApp
            case shouldExpand of
              True -> do t <- newTVar Star
                         (e_left :: Expr (b -> a))  <- unsafeCoerce $ sample (t ->- tp)
                         (e_right :: Expr b) <- unsafeCoerce $ sample (fromType (eType e_left))
                         return $ e_left <> e_right -- return application
              False -> do let cs = map fst . runTI $ filterExprsByType exprs tp
                          guard (not . null $ cs) 
                          i <- getRandomR (0, length cs - 1)
                          return $ unsafeCoerce (cs !! i) 

----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------

main = replicateM 100 $ 
       do let out =  runTI $ do sampleFromExprs library (TAp tList tInt) 
          x <- catch (liftM (Just . fst)  out)
                     (\_ -> putStrLn "error" >> return Nothing)                       
          case x of 
            Just y  -> putStrLn $ show x ++ " " ++ show (unsafeCoerce (eval y) :: [Int])
            Nothing  -> putStrLn ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something along these lines meet your needs?

```
import Control.Monad.Random

randomFunction :: (RandomGen r, Random a, Num a, Floating a) => Rand r (a -> a)
randomFunction = do
  (a:b:c:d:_) <- getRandoms
  fromList [(\x -> a + b*x, 1), (\x -> a - c*x, 1), (\x -> sin (a*x), 1)]
    -- Add more functions as needed

main = do
  let f = evalRand randomFunction (mkStdGen 1) :: Double -> Double
  putStrLn . show $ f 7.3
```

---

**EDIT:** Building on that idea, we could incorporate functions that have different numbers and types of parameters... as long as we partially apply them so that they all have the same result type.

```
import Control.Monad.Random

type Value = (Int, Double, String) -- add more as needed

type Function = Value -> String -- or whatever the result type is

f1 :: Int -> Int -> (Int, a, b) -> Int
f1 a b (x, _, _) = a*x + b

f2 :: String -> (a, b, String) -> String
f2 s (_, _, t) = s ++ t

f3 :: Double -> (a, Double, b) -> Double
f3 a (_, x, _) = sin (a*x)

randomFunction :: RandomGen r => Rand r Function
randomFunction = do
  (a:b:c:d:_) <- getRandoms -- some integers
  (w:x:y:z:_) <- getRandoms -- some floats
  n <- getRandomR (0,100)
  cs <- getRandoms -- some characters
  let s = take n cs 
  fromList [(show . f1 a b, 1), (show . f2 s, 1), (show . f3 w, 1)]
    -- Add more functions as needed

main = do
  f <- evalRandIO randomFunction :: IO Function
  g <- evalRandIO randomFunction :: IO Function
  h <- evalRandIO randomFunction :: IO Function
  putStrLn . show $ f (3, 7.3, "hello")
  putStrLn . show $ g (3, 7.3, "hello")
  putStrLn . show $ h (3, 7.3, "hello")
```

Comment: I don't think so. This just returns one function from a list of functions all of whom have the same type. In my situation I have a list of functions of arbitrary polymorphic type, and I want to generate functions from applications of functions from the list.

Comment: I've added a more detailed example of what I'm talking about. As long as the functions are partially applied to the point where they have the same type, you can even put them in a list.